# new Date() gives me the wrong GMT

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to obtain a date in GMT+1, which corresponds to my zone [(Europe/Paris)](https://24timezones.com/fr/difference/paris/gmt).

When creating a date from scratch, I get a date in GMT+1, as expected:

```
$ new Date()
Thu Oct 31 2019 15:21:15 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)
```

However I have to use the string `2119/08/15 19:00:00+01:00` *(I did not choose this format)* to create a date, and it gives my a GMT+2, while I expect a GMT+1:

```
$ new Date('2019/08/15 19:00:00+01:00')
Tue Aug 15 2019 20:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
```

What's wrong with `2119/08/15 19:00:00+01:00` ? Why can't I get a GMT+1 using this string ?

Comment: On October 31st day light saving times has ended which makes the offset from GMT different than during daylight savings. If you want to do an actual comparison choose the same month and day and make sure that the offset from GMT will be the same as even then it could vary.

Comment: Daylight saving. Though i may stop in France in 1 or 2 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `October 31st` day light saving times has ended which makes the offset from GMT different than during daylight savings which is the offset for your second date of `August 15th`.

If you want to do an actual comparison choose the same month and day and make sure that the offset from GMT will be the same as even then it could vary.